# Matching operator somewhere in Proto expression

Tags: boost-proto

Why doesn't the following `Boost.Proto` grammar match dereference operator, and what's the
correct way to do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/proto/proto.hpp>

namespace proto = boost::proto;
using proto::_;

struct has_deref : proto::or_<
    proto::dereference<_>,
    proto::nary_expr<_, proto::vararg<has_deref>>
    >
{};

template<class Expr>
void test_expr(const Expr &e)
{
    proto::display_expr(e);
    std::cout << "matches? " << std::boolalpha << proto::matches<Expr,
has_deref>::value << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    test_expr(proto::lit(1) + *proto::lit(2));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your definition your `has_deref` grammar matches expressions that are either:

- A dereference operator applied to ANY expression
- ANY n-ary (which can be unary like: `complement`, `negate` or `unary_plus`; binary like: `subscript` or `plus`; ternary like `if_else_`, or directly n-ary like `function`) expression whose arguments recursively match the `has_deref` grammar.

In your example you have a `plus<terminal<int>,dereference<terminal<int> > >` which is something like `binary_expr<tag::plus,terminal<int>,unary_expr<tag::dereference,terminal<int> > >`. When trying to match your expression (I think) Proto tries first the first element of your grammar (`dereference<_>`) and obviously fails. Then tries the second one and `binary_expr<tag::plus,...>` matches `nary_expr<_,...>` and so it recursively tries to match the grammar to both argument expressions of the `plus`. The second one matches directly, but the first one (`terminal<int>`) does not match either of the possibilities and so the whole expression fails to match.

One possible (and sadly clunky) approach to do what you want could be something like:

```cpp
struct has_deref : proto::or_< //ignoring if_then_else and function
    proto::dereference<_>, 
    proto::unary_expr<_, has_deref>,
    proto::binary_expr<_, has_deref, _>, 
    proto::binary_expr<_, _, has_deref>
    > 
{};
```

that matches expressions that are either:

- A dereference operator applied to ANY expression.
- A unary operator applied to expressions that recursively match `has_deref`.
- A binary operator whose first operand is an expression that matches `has_deref` and its second is ANY expression (including expressions that match `has_deref`) .
- A binary operator whose first operand is an expression that does not match `has_deref` and its second is one that does.

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/343782dfac6cb045) is an example that checks that several expressions match this new grammar (extended to also check for functions with at most 2 arguments):

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
#include <boost/proto/proto.hpp> 

namespace proto = boost::proto; 
using proto::_; 

template <typename Grammar>
struct function_contains_at_least_one : proto::or_<//this is awful, there should be a better way
    proto::function<Grammar>,
    proto::function<Grammar,_>,
    proto::function<_,Grammar>,
    proto::function<Grammar,_,_>,
    proto::function<_,Grammar,_>,
    proto::function<_,_,Grammar>
    >
{};

struct has_deref : proto::or_< //ignoring if_else_
    proto::dereference<_>, 
    proto::unary_expr<_,has_deref>,
    proto::binary_expr<_, _,has_deref>, 
    proto::binary_expr<_,has_deref,_>,
    function_contains_at_least_one<has_deref>
    > 
{}; 

template<class Expr> 
void test_expr(const std::string& repr, const Expr &e) 
{ 
    std::cout << repr << " matches 'has_deref'? " << std::boolalpha << proto::matches<Expr, 
has_deref>::value << std::endl; 
    //display_expr(e);
} 


#define TEST_EXPR( EXPR ) test_expr(#EXPR,EXPR)

int main() 
{ 
    using proto::lit;
    TEST_EXPR(lit(1) + lit(2));
    TEST_EXPR(lit(1) + *lit(2)); 
    TEST_EXPR(*lit(1) + *lit(2));
    TEST_EXPR(*(lit(1) * (lit("foo")+lit(2))));
    TEST_EXPR(+-*lit(1)[~*lit(2)++]);

    //testing functions
    TEST_EXPR( lit(1)() );
    TEST_EXPR( (*lit(1))() );
    TEST_EXPR( lit(1)(lit(2)) );
    TEST_EXPR( (*lit(1))(lit(2)) );
    TEST_EXPR( lit(1)(*lit(2)) );
    TEST_EXPR( lit(1)(lit(2),lit(3)) );
    TEST_EXPR( (*lit(1))(*lit(2),*lit(3)) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance! The grammar you propose, however, seems to match everything, because every expression has terminals. Essentially, my problem is that `nary_expr` matches iff *all* its branches match. Is there anything that match iff *any* branch matches?

Comment: Right, I didn't think that through, maybe something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d1b9f780c646634) (also very lightly tested).

Comment: Thanks, it's nice workaround. Though it's a bit disappointing that there's no direct, concise solution for such a trivial task. Maybe it's worth submitting request for feature :).

Comment: Maybe there is, I'm far from an expert, I just like playing with Proto. [An even uglier approach to account for functions with at most 2 parameters](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/343782dfac6cb045).